# Anaconda - problem with installation R-Studio

Tags: anaconda, rstudio

I click install R-studio, sth is installed but on the button is still written install instead of launch. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try re-install or update anaconda. Happens frequently that there are problems installing and then launching RStudio from within anaconda.
I recommend installing it from the Comprehensive R Archive Network (CRAN), the original source administering it. Check: https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download
Cheers, Tobi